# ASP.net MVC3 with forms authentication and LDAP authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, ldap, formsauthentication

I have asp.net mvc3 application with forms authentication. But the our client request AD authentication as well. But the mvc3 app is hosted outside the clients network. What are the possible solutions for this.

1. Get permission to access the clients network from remote server.
2. Get an API to access the active directory data from webserver.

If we choose opt one how could we access active directory for authentication from outside the client network. I anybody have any idea or better options please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Microsoft security products can support this out of the box but I'm not sure how so I suggest that you direct your question to whoever supplies your client with their Microsoft product support.

If you'd rather build a solution so that you've got more control over how it works a quick search found an interesting approach at https://support.freshservice.com/support/solutions/articles/169196-setting-up-active-directory-single-sign-on-sso-for-remote-authentication where they created a simple ASP.Net web site that used AD authentication for sign-on.  MVC 5 can build a WebApi site that does that just by creating a new project in Visual Studio with the right options.

That site wouldn't have to do anything except confirm that the credentials supplied were valid or not.  Your application would ask the user to enter login / password details, then send a (properly secured) web request to the authentication site to determine whether they're valid.  As long as you keep the communication between your server and the client web service tightly secured this should do what you need without much fuss.  That approach removes the need for your server to communicate directly with the client's AD server.